# How to update cart item quantitty with ajax in laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cart

I want to increment/decrement cart quantity by clicking the button. See this image [preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRm8G.png)

This cart row is shown by forcach loop. First row is working perfectly. The problem is, when I click on the seceond/last row, I get only first row value. I don't know how to solve that. Here is view code

```
    @foreach ($carts as $cart)
                            <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" class="id" value="{{ $cart->id }}">
                            <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
                                <td class="product-remove">
                                    <a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeCart({{ $cart->id }})"
                                        aria-label="Remove this item">
                                        <span class="lnr lnr-cross-circle"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                                    <a href="">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('/storage/items/food/' . $cart->FoodItem->image) }}"
                                            class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" /
                                            height="60" width="80">
                                    </a>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-name" data-title="Product">
                                    <a href="shop-single.html">{{ $cart->FoodItem->name }}</a>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-price" data-title="Price">
                                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                            class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>{{ $cart->price }}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <input type="number" class="input-text qty text input-quantity "
                                            class="quantity" step="1" min="0" name="quantity[]"
                                            value="{{ $cart->quantity }}" title="Qty" size="4">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <a href="#" class="number-button  plus">+</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="number-button minus">-</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Total">
                                    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                                            class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> <span
                                            class="sum">{{ $cart->total_price }}</span></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Here is ajax code

```
    $(document).on('click', '.qty', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var quantity = $('.input-quantity').val();  
        var id = $('.id').val();

          $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",

                quantity: quantity,
                id: id,
            },
```

Here my controller code

```
   $cart = Cart::findOrFail($id);
    $cart->update([
        'quantity'    => $request->quantity,
        'total_price' => $cart['price'] * $request->quantity,

    ]);
```

Can anyone tell me way how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
    var quantity = $('.input-quantity').val();  
    var id = $('.id').val();
```

jQuery fetch's the value of the **first item with class** `.input-quantity` every time because you've used this:

```
$('.input-quantity')
```

so you should tell it to pass the value for related item to the clicked item:

```
$(document).on('click', '.qty', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // $(this) mentions the clicked element (target)
    var quantity = $(this).val();  // trasnlate: pass the value of the clicked  (target) element
    ....

}
```

Also I didn't find you've set `id` anywhere! so you can set as as an data-attribute like this:

```
<input data-id={{ $cart->id }} type="number" 
       class="input-text qty text input-quantity "
       step="1" min="0" name="quantity[]"
       value="{{ $cart->quantity }}" title="Qty" size="4">
```

then you can use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.qty', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // $(this) mentions the clicked element (target)
    var quantity = $(this).val();  // trasnlate: pass the value of the clicked  (target) element
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    ....

}
```

You must consider that you've used `class` twice for an element:

```
class="input-text qty text input-quantity "  class="quantity"
```

that is absolutely wrong

Comment: I applied your way. I got quantity and id while clicking on the input field. But I want to get that value when I click on the plus/minus button. How can I get value when I click on the button?

Comment: you mean total_price?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the triggered `event` to your advantage whilst trying to identify which elements to query for values in your ajax function. The `event` has several properties which are useful to you - in this case arguably the most useful is the `target` property which identifies the specific DOM element that invoked the event.

The HTML provided in the question is invalid - the hidden input cannot legitimately exist between table rows - it MUST be in a table cell which is why I moved to the first cell in the row (within the loop)

```
@foreach ($carts as $cart)

    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
        <td class="product-remove">
        
            <!-- move thie hidden element to within a cell -->
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" class="id" value="{{ $cart->id }}">
            
            <a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeCart({{ $cart->id }})" aria-label="Remove this item">
                <span class="lnr lnr-cross-circle"></span>
            </a>
        </td>

        <td class="product-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/items/food/' . $cart->FoodItem->image) }}" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" / height="60" width="80">
            </a>
        </td>

        <td class="product-name" data-title="Product">
            <a href="shop-single.html">{{ $cart->FoodItem->name }}</a>
        </td>

        <td class="product-price" data-title="Price">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>{{ $cart->price }}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
            <div class="quantity">
                <input type="number" class="input-text qty text input-quantity" class="quantity" step="1" min="0" name="quantity[]" value="{{ $cart->quantity }}" title="Qty" size="4">
                <div class="icon">
                    <a href="#" class="number-button  plus">+</a>
                    <a href="#" class="number-button minus">-</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        
        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Total">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
                <span class="sum">{{ $cart->total_price }}</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And with a few minor changes to the javascript

```
const getparent=function(evt,tag){
    let n=evt.target;
    while( n.tagName.toLowerCase()!==tag ) {
        if( n.nodeName==='BODY' )return false;
        n=n.parentNode;
    }
    return n;
}

$(document).on('change', '.qty', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let parent=getparent(e,'tr');

    var quantity = e.target.value;  
    var id = parent.querySelector('td input[ name="cart_id" ]').value;

      $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            quantity: quantity,
            id: id
        },
        success:(r)=>alert(r),
        error:(e)=>alert(e)
    });
```

This is however untested so apologies for any minor errors...